# In C#, how can I get the start/end indexes of all the replacements by the Regex.Replace() function

Tags: c#, regex

I have made a [program](http://www.skytopia.com/software/wildgem/) to highlight on the fly, the phrases in the input matched by a given Regex expression.

However, I want to highlight the replacements in the output panel too. To do this, I need to obtain the indexes and lengths found by Regex.Replace(). Unfortunately, it would seem C# doesn't give access to this data. Have I missed something?

I've thought about manually trying to figure out the indexes by accumulating sums given off from the MatchCollection produced by Regex.Matches(). But this is prone to error, and may not take into account the special $ symbol in the replace expression which could throw the figures off.

There must be a more elegant way.

-------------------- EDIT:

Trying to build off sarh's answer, I've got this so far:

```
public List<Tuple<int, int>> replacementIndexes;

public void mainbody() {
    replacementIndexes = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
    filteredOutput = Regex.Replace(inputText, pattern, match => interceptReplacements(match, replacementText), regexOptions);
}

public string interceptReplacements(Match m, string replacement)
{
    replacementIndexes.Add(new Tuple<int,int>(m.Index,m.Length));
    return replacement;
}
```

Unfortunately, the `interceptReplacements()` method uses the OLD match indexes from the input, and not the new replacement indexes. So we need to get kludgy. Here is a potential 'solution' based on the delta of the replacement lengths versus the match lengths:

```
int delta = 0;
public List<Tuple<int, int>> replacementIndexes;

public void mainbody() {
    delta = 0;
    replacementIndexes = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
    filteredOutput = Regex.Replace(inputText, pattern, match => interceptReplacements(match, replacementText), regexOptions);
}

public string interceptReplacements(Match m, string replacement)
{
    replacementIndexes.Add(new Tuple<int,int>(m.Index+delta, replacement.Length));
    delta += replacement.Length - m.Length;
    return replacement;
}
```

It appeared to work at first, but now a bigger problem has arisen. The $ character (substitution in the replacement) fails to work (it's just treated as a literal). So we're back to square one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex.Replace has an overload [with MatchEvaluator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c(v=vs.110).aspx) which accepts [Match](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c(v=vs.110).aspx) object wich has Index (start position) and Value properties, Value can provide match length (you can calculate end position).

EDIT:
with your latest sample and my comment it will be something like this (not sure regarding syntax, don't have VS right now..)

```
int delta = 0;
public List<Tuple<int, int>> replacementIndexes;
Regex rex;

public void mainbody() {
    delta = 0;
    replacementIndexes = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
    rex = new Regex(pattern);
    filteredOutput = rex.Replace(inputText, match => interceptReplacements(match, replacementText), regexOptions);
}

public string interceptReplacements(Match m, string replacement)
{
    string replacementResult = rex.Replace(m.ToString(), replacement);
    replacementIndexes.Add(new Tuple<int,int>(m.Index+delta, replacementResult.Length));
    delta += replacementResult.Length - m.Length;
    return replacementResult;
}
```

Comment: But if there is more than one replacement, I would need an array of such Matches...? The Regex.Replace() method does them all in one go, so I can't intercept it on each replacement AFAIk.

Comment: I think you can define something like List<Tuple<int, int>> to gather start/end and to add items there in the match evaluator delegate. If after first replacement Index for the second replacement become invalid, i.e. there is some delta between old text length and replacement length, you can calculate this delta during first delegate call and use it in the second delegate call and so on

Comment: Okay I created the delegate, and stored lots of Tuplets. Bad news I'm afraid - the values from `Match m` are the old indexes from the original search, not the new replacement indexes. I suppose it was bound not to work, as the delegate returns the replacement phrase, so any interception would have to be done AFTER that. Any ideas?

Comment: Right. Lets consider string "123-123-123". You replace text "23" with "4". Original indexes of "23" would be 1, 5, 9. When you replace first match with "4" of length 1, next match start = 5 become invalid. But when you do the first replace, you know that string of length 2 was replaced with string of lenth 1 - so you have delta of 1 and you need to reduce next indexes 5,9 to 1 so it will be 4, 8. When you do 2nd replacement at position 4, you know that you need to reduce next position at 1 again in the same way.

Comment: Yes, that was a possibility I brought up in the third paragraph of my question originally. If I was going to take that approach, I might as well have skipped trying to intercept the replacements, and just used the standard `Regex.Matches()` on the input to do it manually. As I said though, I'm reluctant to do that because the $ symbol may complicate matters. There has to be a better way.

Comment: Okay yes I tried out your delta idea, and it does work as expected. However a much more serious problem has cropped up as I originally feared - the $ symbol (substitution ) refuses to work at all as a special replacement character. I'll edit my code to clarify.

Comment: I see.. yes it will not support $ substitutions. The only solution I see for now is to call regex.replace(string, string) inside this delegate. Not quite elegant but it should work. Also, since we will use not the same regex multiple time, I'd advice to make regex object and use its instance methods

Comment: Oh very nice indeed. Be interested to know if there's something more elegant, but I'll be happy to stick with this (I'll probably tick it soon). I wonder where the other guy's answer went. He improved it, and it might've worked in the end.... maybe.

Comment: Found out months later that I have problems with Regex's lookahead/lookbehind (e.g: `(?<=hello)`) where replacing was somehow disabled. But I think I managed to fix it. Instead of `string replacementResult = rex.Replace(m.ToString(), replacement);` as you said, I now use: `string replacementResult = m.Result(replacement);`. Perhaps you can check that and update your answer accordingly. Might make things quicker/elegant too...